# Reading data from excel file: Code not going into Catch() block

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing code to read data from an excel file. Earlier, if I had the Excel file already open, my code went into the 'Catch()' block, and threw an exception for it. Now, it doesn't throw an exception, but it takes a very long time to read. I want to know why it's not going in the 'Catch()' block.

Code:

```
DataTable VendorCodesTable = new DataTable("VendorCodesData");
DataTable ForSheetName = new DataTable("ForSheetName");
string SheetName = "Sheet1$";
try
{
    ExcelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ExcelConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
    ForSheetName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    if (ForSheetName != null)
    {
        SheetName = ForSheetName.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["+SheetName+"]", ExcelConnectionString);
    adapter.Fill(VendorCodesTable);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception");
}
return VendorCodesTable;
```

I added this code and it stopped throwing an error, and took a really long time to load the file:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ExcelConnectionString;
conn.Open();
ForSheetName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
if (ForSheetName != null)
{
    SheetName = ForSheetName.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
}
conn.Close();
```

Now, even if I comment the lines above, it doesn't go into 'Catch()'

Comment: Why do you expect it to go to the catch() block?

Comment: control gets to the catch only if there are any errors in your try block.is ur issue with the load time?

Comment: @TimWilliams: because if my file is currently open, and my code is also trying to access that file, an exception should ideally throw up saying 'file is already being used by another process'

Comment: But it doesn't error, and it does read the data, which suggests that maybe your expectation it will error is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the Query fails if the file is open. maybe it simply waits...
You could test for this condition like this:
VB.NEt code:

```
Private Function FileIsReadable(Path As String) As Boolean
Dim RV As Boolean = True

'tests if the file is open. Returns true if the file is not opened by excel.

Dim stream As IO.FileStream = Nothing
Try
    stream = IO.File.Open(Path, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, IO.FileShare.None)
Catch ex As Exception

    If TypeOf ex Is IO.IOException AndAlso IsFileLocked(ex) Then
        RV = False
    End If
Finally
    If IsNothing(stream) = False Then
        stream.Dispose()
    End If

End Try

Return RV
```

End Function